# Localhost install of wordpress on zend server, style is absent

Tags: wordpress, wamp, zend-server

Here's what i did:
- installed the wordpress db table from a .sql backup file.
- installed all plugins and themes for my site.
- made the site url and wordpress url to be localhost
- also changed the url in the wp_options table to localhost.

But the site only displays the raw html, no styles whatsoever.

*I have read the documentation on permalinks.  I did what was recommended for using WAMP. It didn't help either, I don't even see the wordpress bar on the site at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!!  It was missing some files for some reason in the wp-content folder!  Wow, I thought I was going insane.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) in your `wp-config.php`:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://localhost');
update_option('home','http://localhost');
```

Or if you want a more temporary solution ( this doesn't disturb the database values ), put this in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost');
```

Comment: I did change those in the db, it didn't help.